# Jupyter Notebook: DataFrame constructor not properly called! (ARIMA Model)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, arima

I am getting an error while doing a project using ARIMA Model.

Code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA 
model = ARIMA(train_data['count_log'], order=(2,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit()
output = model_fit.forecast(184) 
valid_data['AR'] = (pd.DataFrame(output[0])).values
```

Error:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)

    <ipython-input-36-5c6958629d0d> in <module>
          1 output = model_fit.forecast(184)
    ----> 2 valid_data['AR'] = (pd.DataFrame(output[0])).values
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
        588         else:
        589             if index is None or columns is None:
    --> 590                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
        591 
        592             if not dtype:
    
    ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Python Version = 3.7.6

Statsmodel = 1.2.0 (After upgrade)

Also, I upgraded Statsmodel version but still I am getting the same error again and again.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(output[0]))` tries to call the constructor of `pd.DataFrame` with a single value, which is not valid. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do in this line?

Comment: @cel I was comparing the results (which is 184 values in forecast function) of AR model in the **valid_data**. That is why I used **pd.Dataframe** for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [0] from the output like this:

`(pd.DataFrame(output)).values`